# CakePHP: Running a function when no one accessing website

Tags: php, cakephp

I want to run some functions that do things like change statuses of records and deleting expired records in a database in my CakePHP. E.g. every 24 hours.

The obvious issue is running a function requires to my knowledge that someone actually access the website. Is it possible to run a function automatically with no user accessing the website to get the code to run?

So for example I have the following code:

```
function garbage() 
    {         
        $deadline = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time() - (24 * 60 * 60)); // keep tickets for 24h. 
        $ticketObj = new Ticket(); 
        $data = $ticketObj->query('DELETE from tickets WHERE created < \''.$deadline.'\''); 
    }
```

This deletes expired tickets that are over 24 hours old. But this runs ONLY when someone is accessing the website. Could it run every night at midnight automatically?

Comment: Implement a cron job with this implementation in CakePHP: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html if you really need this.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to setup a cronjob.

Here's a good guide on how to do it: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/managing-cron-jobs-with-php-2/

Answer (score 2):

You can write your code as [CakePHP Console application](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html#creating-a-shell), and run it as [cronjobs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells/cron-jobs.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it should be done as a cron job.

As far as cake goes, you should use a method in the model and invoke it via a shell.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/console-and-shells.html

Also, your example in the question is not very cake-like.
For example, you should avoid using the `query()` method.

Something like this should be better (this presumes you have a `Ticket` model):

```
<?php 
class Ticket extends AppModel

public function garbage($deadline = null) {
    //http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/deleting-data.html#deleteall
    $this->deleteAll(array($this->alias . 'created <' => $deadline), false);
}
```

Now you can easily reuse this method in a cake shell.